# How to properly type beam.Map with pyright

Tags: apache-beam, pyright

I have beam code like:

```py
def foo(i: int) -> Foo:
  ...
class IntToFoo(beam.PTransform):
  def expand(self, pcoll: PCollection[int]) -> PCollection[Foo]:
    return pcoll | beam.Map(foo)
```

Running *pyright* it complains for the returning line:

```
Expression of type "PValue" cannot be assigned to return type "PCollection[Foo]"
  "PValue" is incompatible with "PCollection[Foo]
```

Now AFAIU it seems like beam does not provide sufficient type hinting.
Is there a way of working around that as a user of beam so that pyright accepts the code (without ignoring the type error).

**EDIT**:

I now tried:

```py
    temp = pcoll | beam.Map(foo)
    assert isinstance(temp, PCollection[Foo])
    return temp
```

Good news is, neither `temp =` nor `return` line has any errors. Bad news is that it complains on isinstance line now:

> TypeVar or generic type with type arguments not allowed

**EDIT 2**:

For now I settled with

```py
temp = pcoll | beam.Map(foo)
return cast(PCollection[Foo], temp)
```

which IMO is still not a solution, because I then would need to specify `PCollection[Foo]` both the signature as well as the cast.

Comment: What happens if you put the isinstance line inside an `if TYPE_CHECKING:` block? (from typing import TYPE_CHECKING). I'm not saying it's a solution to your original question, just curious.

Comment: BTW, is pyright or mypy failing throwing this error?

Comment: pyright is complaining - have not tried mypy yet

Comment: fwiw - we have mypy tests running on the Beam codebase, and they work fine. We have not tried pyright on Beam code : /

Comment: FYI @Pablo - I created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12004 for pyright.

Comment: @Pablo looking at ignores in https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/mypy.ini, "mypy tests" might be a bit of a stretch *cough*